# Why does it instantly have the player lose

Tags: javascript, debugging, p5.js

```js
var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 15;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var celliseaten = false;
var eaten = false;
var zoom = 1;
var n = 0;
var Xgrid = 600;
var Ygrid = 600;
var cpu = [];
var x = 0;
var y = 10;
var z = 100;
var OffSetX = [];
var OffSetY = [];
var lost = false;
var CPUteam = 2;

function setup() {
  smooth();
  frameRate(999)
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  playerX = 500;
  playerY = 100;

}

function draw() {
  var TotalBlue = 0;
  var TotalRed = 0;
  var Total = 0;
  var cellDist = [];
  if (lost) {
    noLoop()
    fill(255)
    textSize(40)
    background(0)
    text("You lost", width / 2.5, height / 2)
    textSize(20)
    text("Final Board: ", 350, 60)
  } else {
    background(220);
    push();

    var Newzoom = 10 / playerSize
    let newnewZoom = 1.3 * lerp(0.9, 10 / playerSize, 0.5)
    Newzoom = lerp(zoom, Newzoom, 0.3)
    translate(Xgrid / 2, Ygrid / 2 - 50);
    scale(newnewZoom)
    translate(-playerX, -playerY);


    playerSpeed = round((playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10000) / 1000
    Newcelltimer++;

    if (Newcelltimer % 40 == 0) {
      cell.push(ceil(random(0 - Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)),
        ceil(random(0 - Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)))
    }

    if (Newcelltimer % 200 == 0) {
      cpu.push(ceil(random(-Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)), ceil(random(-Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)), 20, CPUteam)
      OffSetX.push(ceil(random(0, 1000000)))
      OffSetY.push(ceil(random(1000000, 2000000)))
      CPUteam++;
    }
    if (Newcelltimer == 1 || Newcelltimer == 2) {
      cpu.push(ceil(random(-Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)), ceil(random(-Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)), 20, CPUteam)
      OffSetX.push(ceil(random(0, 1000000)))
      OffSetY.push(ceil(random(1000000, 2000000)))
      CPUteam++;
    }
    //Checks if player Ate cell
    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {
      let d = int(dist(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], playerX, playerY))
      if (d <= playerSize / 2) {
        playerSize += 5;
        cell.splice(i * 2, 2)
        celliseaten = true;
      }
    }
    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && playerY > 0 - Ygrid) {
      playerY -= playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && playerX < 2 * Xgrid) {
      playerX += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && playerY < 2 * Ygrid) {
      playerY += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && playerX > 0 - Xgrid) {
      playerX -= playerSpeed;
    }

    if (Newcelltimer % 200 == 0) {
      cell.splice(0, 2)
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < (cpu.length / 4); j++) {
      var cpuDist = [];
      //Checks if AI ate cell
      for (var n = 0; n < cell.length / 2; n++) {

        let dis = int(dist(cell[n * 2], cell[n * 2 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]))
        if (dis <= cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2) {
          cpu[j * 4 + 2] += 5;
          cell.splice(n * 2, 2)
        } else {
          cellDist.push(dis)
        }
      }
      var ClosestCell = min(cellDist);
      var ClosestCellpos;
      for (var r = 0; r < cell.length / 2; r++) {
        if (ClosestCell == dist(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cell[r * 2], cell[r * 2 + 1])) {
          ClosestCellpos = r;
          break;
        }
      }

      let amp = round((cpu[j * 4 + 2] / Math.pow(cpu[j * 4 + 2], 1.44)) * 10000) / 1000;
      if (r < 100 && dist(playerX, playerY, cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]) > 100 || cpu[j * 4 + 2] > playerSize) {
        var disXpos = cell[r * 2] - cpu[j * 4];
        var disYpos = cell[r * 2 + 1] - cpu[j * 4 + 1];

        disXpos = map(disXpos, -100, 100, -1, 1);
        disYpos = map(disYpos, -100, 100, -1, 1);
        cpu[j * 4] += disXpos * amp;
        cpu[j * 4 + 1] += disYpos * amp;
      } else {
        x += 0.003;
        y += 0.003;
        let offsetX = map(noise(x + OffSetX[j]), 0, 1, -1, 1) * amp;
        let offsetY = map(noise(y + OffSetY[j]), 0, 1, -1, 1) * amp;
        cpu[j * 4] += offsetX;
        cpu[j * 4 + 1] += offsetY;
      }
      //Draws the AI's
      if (cpu[j * 4 + 3] % 2 == 0) {
        fill(0, 0, 255)
        circle(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4 + 2]);
      } else {
        fill(255, 0, 0)
        circle(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4 + 2])
      }
      //Checks if player ate AI or vice versa
      let distance = int(dist(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], playerX, playerY))
      if (distance <= playerSize / 2 && cpu[j * 4 + 2] < playerSize) {
        playerSize += floor(cpu[j * 4 + 2]);
        cpu.splice(j * 4, 4)
      }
      if (distance <= cpu[j * 4 + 2] && cpu[j * 4 + 2] > playerSize) {
        lost = true;
      }

      //Checks if one AI eats another
      for (var m = 0; m < cpu.length / 4; m++) {
        if (m != j) {
          if (cpu[j * 4 + 3] % 2 != cpu[m * 4 + 3] % 2) {
            distant = dist(cpu[m * 4], cpu[m * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1])
            let higher = (cpu[m * 4 + 2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2]) ? cpu[m * 4 + 2] : cpu[j * 4 + 2]

            if (higher > distant) {
              if (cpu[m * 4 + 2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2]) {
                cpu[m * 4 + 2] += cpu[j * 4 + 2]
                cpu.splice(j * 4, 4)
              } else {
                cpu[j * 4 + 2] += cpu[m * 4 + 2]
                cpu.splice(m * 4, 4)
              } //Else
            } // If
          } //If
        } //If
      } //If
    } //Nested For
  } // For
  //Draws all the "cells"
  for (var k = 0; k < cell.length / 2; k++) {

    fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
    circle(cell[k * 2], cell[k * 2 + 1], 7)
  }
  //Nothing important, drawing the smiley face character
  fill(255, 255, 0)
  circle(playerX, playerY, playerSize)
  fill(0)
  ellipse(playerX - playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  ellipse(playerX + playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  arc(playerX, playerY + playerSize / 5, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  fill(255, 255, 0)
  noStroke()
  arc(playerX, (playerY + playerSize / 5) - 1, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  stroke(0)
  //Limits the max player size
  if (playerSize >= 3 * Xgrid | playerSize >= 3 * Ygrid) {
    if (Xgrid > Ygrid) {
      playerSize = 3 * Ygrid;
    } else {
      playerSize = 3 * Xgrid;
    }
  }
}

VS


var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 15;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var celliseaten = false;
var eaten = false;
var zoom = 1;
var n = 0;
var Xgrid = 600;
var Ygrid = 600;
var cpu = [];
var x = 0;
var y = 10;
var z = 100;
var OffSetX = [];
var OffSetY = [];
var lost = false;
var CPUteam = 2;

function setup() {
  smooth();
  frameRate(999)
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  playerX = 500;
  playerY = 100;

}

function draw() {
  var TotalBlue = 0;
  var TotalRed = 0;
  var Total = 0;
  var cellDist = [];
  if (lost) {
    noLoop()
    fill(255)
    textSize(40)
    background(0)
    text("You lost", width / 2.5, height / 2)
    textSize(20)
    text("Final Board: ", 350, 60)
  } else {
    background(220);
    push();

    var Newzoom = 10 / playerSize
    let newnewZoom = 1.3 * lerp(0.9, 10 / playerSize, 0.5)
    Newzoom = lerp(zoom, Newzoom, 0.3)
    translate(Xgrid / 2, Ygrid / 2 - 50);
    scale(newnewZoom)
    translate(-playerX, -playerY);


    playerSpeed = round((playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10000) / 1000
    Newcelltimer++;

    if (Newcelltimer % 40 == 0) {
      cell.push(ceil(random(0 - Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)),
        ceil(random(0 - Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)))
    }

    if (Newcelltimer % 200 == 0) {
      cpu.push(ceil(random(-Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)), ceil(random(-Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)), 20, CPUteam)
      OffSetX.push(ceil(random(0, 1000000)))
      OffSetY.push(ceil(random(1000000, 2000000)))
      CPUteam++;
    }
    if (Newcelltimer == 1 || Newcelltimer == 2) {
      cpu.push(ceil(random(-Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)), ceil(random(-Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)), 20, CPUteam)
      OffSetX.push(ceil(random(0, 1000000)))
      OffSetY.push(ceil(random(1000000, 2000000)))
      CPUteam++;
    }
    //Checks if player Ate cell
    for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {
      let d = int(dist(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], playerX, playerY))
      if (d <= playerSize / 2) {
        playerSize += 5;
        cell.splice(i * 2, 2)
        celliseaten = true;
      }
    }
    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && playerY > 0 - Ygrid) {
      playerY -= playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && playerX < 2 * Xgrid) {
      playerX += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW) && playerY < 2 * Ygrid) {
      playerY += playerSpeed;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && playerX > 0 - Xgrid) {
      playerX -= playerSpeed;
    }

    if (Newcelltimer % 200 == 0) {
      cell.splice(0, 2)
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < (cpu.length / 4); j++) {
      var cpuDist = [];
      //Checks if AI ate cell
      for (var n = 0; n < cell.length / 2; n++) {

        let dis = int(dist(cell[n * 2], cell[n * 2 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]))
        if (dis <= cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2) {
          cpu[j * 4 + 2] += 5;
          cell.splice(n * 2, 2)
        }
      }

      let amp = round((cpu[j * 4 + 2] / Math.pow(cpu[j * 4 + 2], 1.44)) * 10000) / 1000;
      x += 0.003;
      y += 0.003;
      let offsetX = map(noise(x + OffSetX[j]), 0, 1, -1, 1) * amp;
      let offsetY = map(noise(y + OffSetY[j]), 0, 1, -1, 1) * amp;
      cpu[j * 4] += offsetX;
      cpu[j * 4 + 1] += offsetY;
      //Draws the AI's
      if (cpu[j * 4 + 3] % 2 == 0) {
        fill(0, 0, 255)
        circle(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4 + 2]);
      } else {
        fill(255, 0, 0)
        circle(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4 + 2])
      }
      //Checks if player ate AI or vice versa
      let distance = int(dist(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], playerX, playerY))
      if (distance <= playerSize / 2 && cpu[j * 4 + 2] < playerSize) {
        playerSize += floor(cpu[j * 4 + 2]);
        cpu.splice(j * 4, 4)
      }
      if (distance <= cpu[j * 4 + 2] && cpu[j * 4 + 2] > playerSize) {
        lost = true;
      }

      //Checks if one AI eats another
      for (var m = 0; m < cpu.length / 4; m++) {
        if (m != j) {
          if (cpu[j * 4 + 3] % 2 != cpu[m * 4 + 3] % 2) {
            distant = dist(cpu[m * 4], cpu[m * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1])
            let higher = (cpu[m * 4 + 2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2]) ? cpu[m * 4 + 2] : cpu[j * 4 + 2]

            if (higher > distant) {
              if (cpu[m * 4 + 2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2]) {
                cpu[m * 4 + 2] += cpu[j * 4 + 2]
                cpu.splice(j * 4, 4)
              } else {
                cpu[j * 4 + 2] += cpu[m * 4 + 2]
                cpu.splice(m * 4, 4)
              } //Else
            } // If
          } //If
        } //If
      } //If
    } //Nested For
  } // For
  //Draws all the "cells"
  for (var k = 0; k < cell.length / 2; k++) {

    fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
    circle(cell[k * 2], cell[k * 2 + 1], 7)
  }
  //Nothing important, drawing the smiley face character
  fill(255, 255, 0)
  circle(playerX, playerY, playerSize)
  fill(0)
  ellipse(playerX - playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  ellipse(playerX + playerSize / 5, playerY - playerSize / 10, playerSize / 5, playerSize / 3)
  arc(playerX, playerY + playerSize / 5, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  fill(255, 255, 0)
  noStroke()
  arc(playerX, (playerY + playerSize / 5) - 1, playerSize / 2, playerSize / 5, 0, 3.2, PIE)
  stroke(0)
  //Limits the max player size
  if (playerSize >= 3 * Xgrid | playerSize >= 3 * Ygrid) {
    if (Xgrid > Ygrid) {
      playerSize = 3 * Ygrid;
    } else {
      playerSize = 3 * Xgrid;
    }
  }
}
```

Firstly I know this is NOT even close to the minimum reproducible code, but I tried to clean it up with some comments. I'm not exactly sure what to delete, so I'm 100% open to any edits made on this post. With that said, my question is why isn't the top one working. I should clear up what I'm trying to do, which in pseudo-code would look something like this:

1. Return an array with all the distances between the cell and AI
2. Find the smallest value in that array
3. Find out the X and Y pos of the cell
4. Check if the smallest value in that array is less than an arbitrary 100, **AND EITHER** the AI's size is bigger than the player's, **OR** the distance between the player and the AI is less than another arbitrary 100

   1. If it's false, go on to calculate the AI's next move using Perlin noise
   2. If it's true, calculate the X distance and the Y distance the AI is away from the cell

      - Use those distances, map it out to -1 and 1, and multiply it by the amplitude, then simply move the AI by the value you get.

I'm asking for WHY isn't this workings firstly, and how to make it work.
I suspect that the AI's are going crazy out of control all around the map, and because the AI's initial size is larger than the players, the player loses.

Odds are my program won't load in the snippet tool, so here are the links to the programs on the Web Editor

The first one(Not working) - https://editor.p5js.org/Meowmeow/sketches/5725Ik6AF

The second one(Working) - https://editor.p5js.org/Meowmeow/sketches/XTH-hArn6

If the question is unclear, please write a comment on what you don't understand, because I'm not sure if someone else without any background information would have a hard time understanding what's going on.

EDIT) Just realized the list doesn't work for the pseudo-code, I don't have any time to fix it right now. (FIXED)

-EDIT)
Just to clear it up, I want the CPUs to have a more strategic, and less random path, and to do that I'm first doing the following stated above (Having the CPU eat a cell if there's one nearby)

Comment: I feel like your request in the body of the question doesn't really match its title do you want to clarify that?

Comment: This might be old news but I think the CPUs are flying towards the player at ridiculous speeds so the player instantly looses unless you reduce what seems to be the CPU spawn-size, in which case the CPUs are instantly consumed by the player who gets a random-seeming score boost... also I think some object oriented programming could make your code a little more intuitive and easy to read for other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the player instantly loses is because the code that the code that checks AI "cpu" distance to player doesn't work correctly.

```js
      var cpuDist = [];
      //Checks if AI ate cell
      for (var n = 0; n < cell.length / 2; n++) {
        let dis = int(dist(cell[n * 2], cell[n * 2 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]))
        if (dis <= cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2) {
          cpu[j * 4 + 2] += 5;
          cell.splice(n * 2, 2)
        } else {
          cellDist.push(dis)
        }
      }
      // NOTE: if there are no entries in cpu for which the condition in the above if block was false, then cellDist will be empty
      var ClosestCell = min(cellDist);
      // NOTE: if cellDist is empty, then ClosestCell will be Infinity
      var ClosestCellpos;
      for (var r = 0; r < cell.length / 2; r++) {
        // NOTE: If ClosestCell is Infinity than this will never be true, and ClosestCellpos will be undefined
        if (ClosestCell == dist(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cell[r * 2], cell[r * 2 + 1])) {
          ClosestCellpos = r;
          break;
        }
      }

      let amp = round((cpu[j * 4 + 2] / Math.pow(cpu[j * 4 + 2], 1.44)) * 10000) / 1000;
      // NOTE: This is bad form: using r from the above for loop. If you are going to use a variable that is initialized/incremented by a for loop you should declare it separately outside of the for loop. Perhaps you should be using ClosestCellpos instead of r?
      // NOTE: r < 100 is strange. what does that mean/matter? is cell.length / 2 guaranteed to be >= 100?
      if (r < 100 &&
          dist(playerX, playerY, cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]) > 100 ||
          // NOTE: because this is after a logical OR this can succeed even if the value of r is >= cell.length / 2
          cpu[j * 4 + 2] > playerSize) {

        // NOTE: when r is >= cell.length / 2 + 1 one or both of these become NaN
        var disXpos = cell[r * 2] - cpu[j * 4];
        var disYpos = cell[r * 2 + 1] - cpu[j * 4 + 1];

        // When disXpos or disYpos are NaN we start putting NaN values into the cpu array
        disXpos = map(disXpos, -100, 100, -1, 1);
        disYpos = map(disYpos, -100, 100, -1, 1);
        cpu[j * 4] += disXpos * amp;
        cpu[j * 4 + 1] += disYpos * amp;
      }

      // .........

      // NOTE: the int() function converts NaN into 0, which is unfortunate. You should use floor() instead of int()
      let distance = int(dist(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], playerX, playerY))
      if (distance <= playerSize / 2 && cpu[j * 4 + 2] < playerSize) {
        playerSize += floor(cpu[j * 4 + 2]);
        cpu.splice(j * 4, 4)
      }
      // NOTE: Once distance is zero because if the above series of notes, this becomes true, which happens immediately
      if (distance <= cpu[j * 4 + 2] && cpu[j * 4 + 2] > playerSize) {
        lost = true;
      }
```

Here's a [working version](http://oppr.org/s/NT5LRBkF). I moved to OpenProcessing.org because the p5js.org editor doesn't work well for debugging. I was able to find this issue by simply throwing a `debugger;` statement right before `list = true;` and then working backwards. You'll need to open your browsers developer tools panel for `debugger;` statements to work.

Note: there are a lot of code smell issues with this sketch that make it hard to debug.

1. Don't use `var`, ever. Always use `let` instead.
2. The cell and cpu data structures are confusing and hard to follow. Instead of packing x and y values into arrays like this it would be much better to represent these data structures as arrays of objects. I still don't understand all of the `n * 2` and `j * 4` indexes into these arrays. There as got to be a better way to model your state.

However you did well to provide a link to a runnable example, without this it would have been impossible to identify your issue.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't understand objects very much, and I'm still learning how to properly use them. So I had no clue how to do it with objects at the beginning when I started.

Comment: Also the r<100 is my mistake. it's supposed to be the distance between the cell and the Ai is less than 100.